# Paypal IPN Listener. what is the url I give paypal to post it to?

Tags: networking, paypal

Hey i'm running wamp server on windows 7 i get my Internet through at&t. The problem is I have a new ip address almost everyday according to google. Is there a way i can set up my local network to give my wamp server a real permanent ip address and allow paypal to post to my listener? It is a 2wire Gateway router. Any help would be great this is a school project so i am rather new with all this.

Comment: No. You need to pay your ISP for a static IP. Barring that, you need to host your site elsewhere (get a hosting provider, they can be rather cheap). Alternatively you can use something like no-ip or dyndns to convert your dynamic ip into a fixed hostname. I wouldn't do this however, because there's usually a small update delay which would be detrimental to a financial transaction.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to pay your ISP for a static IP. Barring that, you need to host your site elsewhere (get a hosting provider, they can be rather cheap). Alternatively you can use something like no-ip or dyndns to convert your dynamic ip into a fixed hostname. I wouldn't do this however, because there's usually a small update delay which would be detrimental to a financial transaction. – Chris Nov 19 at 0:38
Thank you chris this at least gives me options